# Вывод определенных элементов массива

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть одномерный массив **a**, нужно вывести все элементы массива начиная от **K** и заканчивая **N** элементом массива:

```
a[1] = 3;
a[2] = 6;
a[3] = 9;
....
a[K] = 12; //например
a[83] = 3934;
a[N] = 32738247239; //например
```

Числа **N** и **K** заранее неизвестны, их выставляет пользователь.

Подскажите, можно ли выполнить данную задачу **без** использования массивов?

Comment: "Есть одномерный массив", "можно ли выполнить ... без использования массивов" ??

Comment: `Есть одномерный массив a`, без использования массивов у вас нету массива `a`, но, если сильно надо, просто представте, что `a` это обьект и `a[K]` это просто свойство обьекта `a` имеющее имя `K` (что в общем как-то так и есть)

Comment: Есть хороший ресурс https://learn.javascript.ru. Там можете найти все по скриптам.